# i need help understanding this batch script

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting

i dont under stand the

forfiles -p

or the

/C "cmd /c del @path"

what do they do they mean

[image]

Comment: Type `forfiles /?` and `cmd /?` for help. `CMD` is the command processor and running the `DEL` command. `/c` means exit after running command. `Forfiles` substitutes the path and name of the file for `@path`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it does the following. 
For each files in c:\test that contains .jpg format and are 0 days old or older will be deleted.

*Commands explained...*

**Forfiles -p**  : Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. **-p**: The Path to search (default=current folder)

**/C command**   : The command to execute for each file.
                Wrap the command string in double quotes.
                Default = "cmd /c echo @file"

**CMD /c** : Start a new CMD shell and run Command and then terminate

**Del** : Delete

**@path**   :  Full path of the file.

More details at http://ss64.com/